# cmake build dir stored in ramdisk and symlinked to project causes make to fail

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, ramdisk

I'm trying to speed up build process using ramdisk for build directory.

I've created ramdisk:

```
sudo mount -t tmpfs -o size=1024m tmpfs /mnt/ramdisk
```

On ramdisk I've created build dir:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/
```

Then I've symlinked ramdisk build dir to project in which I want to use this directory:

```
cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3
ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/ build
```

After this I did classic combo for building project:

```
cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3/build
cmake ..
make
```

But above command does not worked because relative path (`cmake ..`) is translated to `/mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3` and not to `/home/wakatana/rust/hello3/` (I suspect that this is whole problem)

So instead of classic combo I did a little bit modified combo (when build dir is not symlinked this works):

```
cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3/build
cmake /home/wakatana/rust/hello3
make
```

But this ends up with errors during `make` phase:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wakatana/rust/hello3/build
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '../src/lib.rs', needed by 'src/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/libtest_lib.a'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:122: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/test-lib_target.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/test-lib_target.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is it possible to somehow tell to cmake/make to deal symlinks correctly?

Comment: So why not `cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3 && cmake -S. -B/mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/ && cmake --build /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/`?

Comment: This worked as expected. Thank you very much. Please post it as answer co I can accept it. One little node instead of `cmake -S.` I have to use `cmake -S .`

Comment: Ugh, that cmake option parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save yourself the trouble of creating symlinks and work on the ram disc:

```
cmake -S /home/wakatana/rust/hello3 -B /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/
cmake --build /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/
```

You could create the symlink, and then work from parent dir:

```
ln -s /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build/
cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3 
cmake -S .  -B build
cmake --build build
# or expand the symlink before cmake has to:
cmake -S .  -B "$(readlink -f "./build")"
cmake --build "$(readlink -f "./build")"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other way is to rebind your RAM disk into your project tree instead of symlinking:

```
$ cd /home/wakatana/rust/hello3
$ mkdir -p build
$ mount --bind /mnt/ramdisk/rust/hello3/build build
```